# How to change the size of right-click menu

Tags: themes, cursor, context-menu

I am using Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS. When I right click cursor this menu opens very large.

[image]

I want to make it small in size. How can I do that?

Comment: Dear @pomsky, It is Latest Ubuntu 18.04.1 Standard-Ubuntu

Comment: One easy but non-elegant way is to try different application themes (GTK+). You can change it using GNOME Tweaks.